# Queue members are not getting email notification

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Whenever I assign a case to Queue, the users in that particular queue are not getting email notification, that the cases are allotted to them. I have checked the following:

1. In the support settings, send email notification when case owner is changed is checked.
2. In the deliverability, it is set to "All Email"
3. The user have the read/write permission to that particular record as well

Even after this, nothing seems to be working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Queue's definition?

[image: "Send Email to members" checkbox is not selected]

And if you use assignment rules - in each step you might want to specify the email template.

Comment: Yes, I have marked it as well. Still not receiving email notification

Comment: What (if anything) is in setup -> email log files. Maybe SF tries to send them out but the address is wrong or you use "email relay" that swallows them. And have you tried looking at a debug log? Are there any enqueued emails?

Answer (score 0):

go to Setup > Process Automation Settings > Enable 'Send an email each time automation updates the same record' set to true